# Not able to execute the test case throughly in one go says Class is implemented in both, One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I am facing the issue while executing the UnitTestcase.
Build is getting succeed but before it start testing app is getting crashed.

Here is my `Appdelegate.swift` file code.

```
func appDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

here I just created returned appDelegateClass object globally so I can use where ever I need.

and it's crashing at this beginning line only.
I tried removing this and created appDelegate object locally as well, still issue persist.

I also tried by creating `FakeAppdelegate.Swift` class to make sure that App with have AppDelegate.swift and TestCases will have `FakeAppDelegate.swift` but still app crash at the same point.

Following is the error that I am getting on console.

```
Class PodsDummy_GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport is implemented in both /Users/Sagar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/90E56A8B-6AFD-4854-9C0B-2C67CC226904/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/456D9F5F-1AD2-4EAC-AD76-78BD6207FD42/CDHApplication.app/CDHApplication (0x108386370) and /Users/Sagar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CDHApplication-ewxqnitieunyqhbtjauiqpjosuqk/Build/Products/CD(SIT)-iphonesimulator/CDHApplication.app/PlugIns/CDHApplicationTests.xctest/CDHApplicationTests (0x10a2b9d98). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I am not using any PODS.
I am using Swift Package Manager.

I am getting same error above mentioned for many classes that are referenced inside the frameworks.
I tried making frameworks option, wont help but.

How can I solve this and execute my unit test cases.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.